# Can't get php insert to work

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

Sorry, I'm new to php / mysql. I'm trying to change an existing script to take the results and then insert the value into the database.

This is what I've tried. I'm guessing I'm missing something or the syntax is wrong:

```
// unique reference number is generated.  
// check if it exists or not  
$query = "SELECT `ID_UNIQUE` FROM `tbl_referrals` 
          WHERE `ID_UNIQUE`='".$unique_ref."'";  
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error().' '.$query);  
if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {  

    // We've found a unique number. Lets set the $unique_ref_found  
    // variable to true and exit the while loop  
    $unique_ref_found = true;  

$sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_referrals` (`ID_UNIQUE`)
       VALUES
     (`ID_UNIQUE`)";
    }  

}  

echo 'Your reference number is: '.$unique_ref;
```

Comment: You're treating your values like a column, instead of a string. You also have an undefined variable `$unique_ref`. Plus, you're missing `mysql_query()` for the insert.

Answer (score 1):

Ticks are for identifiers, single quotes are for string values:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_referrals` (`ID_UNIQUE`)
       VALUES
     ('ID_UNIQUE')";
}
```

Comment: Let's hope that undefined `$unique_ref` variable doesn't bite us in the *you know what* ;) ah, it's probably defined somewhere... somewhere. Plus missing `mysql_query()` for it too.

Comment: That missing `mysql_query()` *might* be important. I'm hoping it was omitted for brevity. :/

Comment: You know me; I take posted code *literally*. - OP -> *Sorry, I'm new to php / mysql.* (wink)

Comment: That's never a bad idea around here

Comment: All so many times I've seen it, just as you have; *am sure* ;-) then they come back and say: *It doesn't work*.

Comment: Did you hear a *poof* - ? The sound of OP, vanishing into thin air.